# Kendo Grid initialized from HTML table - get entire data object

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using Kendo Grid on an existing HTML table which is fine.

I'd like to do other stuff with the data. I've figured out how to get the `dataItem` for a selected row, but I'd also like to use the entire data source (i.e. the 'converted' HTML items) on the `dataBound` event.

I'm sure this is pretty simple, I just don't know where to look for the 'raw' data.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you want to find `dataItem` and `datasource` for particular grid `row` right?

Comment: Can you add more clarify to your question. What is it exactly that you want?

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear. Basically, when you initialize a Kendo Grid from a table, it must convert the HTML in the table to a javascript object. I just wanted to access that object as soon as it's available. I think I've figured it out though.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the 'official' way to access the data, but it works. This is added to the Grid configuration:

```
dataBound: function(e) {
  var data = this.dataSource.options.data;
}
```

Pretty simple really. Don't know why I couldn't find it sooner.